# Передача значения из метода в метод

Tags: c#, методы

Добрый день!
Есть метод заполняющий treeview дисками. Есть метод заполняющий listview файлами и папками. При заполнении файлами в свойствах каждого элемента уже есть нужный мне параметр - FullPath. Мне необходимо значение этого параметра выделенного элемента передать в другой метод для сравнения(в моем случае тот, что отрабатывает по нажатию кнопки). Как это можно сделать?

Comment: у вас приложение какого типа?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

в ListViewItem есть свойство tag объектного типа, ему можно присваивать что угодно. В твоем случае - FullPath. Далее в методе сравнения получаешь выделенный элемент и читаешь его свойство tag

Comment: ...какая здесь необходимость использовать `Tag`?

Comment: вы предложили какую-либо альтернативу? Ответ на вопрос: "Мне необходимо значение этого параметра выделенного элемента передать в другой метод для сравнения" я дал в полной мере

Comment: и близко нет. Альтернатива очевидна - разделять работу с данными и представление.

Comment: считаю очень неэффективным погружать такого человека в область MVC, у которого возникают подобные вопросы. Для этого нужен хороший опыт

Comment: сказки. Намного проще сразу делать по логике, чем потом переучиваться.